# Instant Messenger proxy with web-based, searchable chat logs and mobile support

Tags: instant-messaging, google-talk, jabber

Does anybody here know of a decent setup for having multiple computers and devices (iPhone/Android) logged into the same IM accounts (yahoo, gtalk, AIM) with consolidated web-based chat logs?

I've tried/thought of a few approaches:

- IRC w/ IRSSI and bitlbee (was nice, but not a great solution for phones and chat logs were painful)
- Google Talk (would be great if I could just use this, but I need to support Yahoo - perhaps a Jabber relay?)
- Meebo (can this be used as a proxy?)

Answer (score 1):

That was basically my first question on [aardvark](http://vark.com/t/4dcdf5).

I know just of 3 good options:

- As Alexander said, **Google Talk**. You have to [configure it](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2006-05-02-n79.html) using another Jabber Client such as Psy, on linux. The keywords here are *gateway* and *transport*. It's not easy, but this will give you the best results.
- As you've suggested, **a web client**. There are many clients out there, [nimbuzz](http://nimbuzz.com) is the best for smartphones nowadays; [e-buddy](http://ebuddy.com) has the simplest interface and the less bugs, but also the less features; and find [imo.imm](https://imo.im/) even better than meebo but [**meebo**](http://meebo.com) is the only one with good chat history.
- **[IM-history](http://im-history.com)** for a paid solution. This will even send your skype chat to GTalk, something you can't do with the first option alone. At least I don't know of any jabber gateway for Skype.

For the first option, which is what I use, I would quote some [links](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=658940) from my vark's answer, to give you an idea it won't be easy to configure. But it's too big. Granted, once set up, you'll have all working even inside **Gmail**.

Answer (score 0):

Google Talk (which is XMPP/Jabber). The logs show up in your web client by default.

Comment: Google Talk is close, but I need to be able to log Yahoo IM chats (the primary protocol used by coworkers).

Comment: You can interoperate Yahoo, MSN, etc with XMPP federation with Google Talk. Google for more info.

Comment: Good stuff, but lack of info, Alex.

Comment: @Cawas: I'm not really into spoonfeeding. I provided more than enough detail to point OP in the correct direction. Would you rather I regurgitate the Google Talk documentation here?

Comment: I just think you could've added more info. I think the idea in here is giving the fish and pointing how to learning oneself "how to fish" if one wants really to.

Answer (score 0):

[Barracuda IM Firewall](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/im_overview.php) or [IMSpector](http://www.imspector.org/wordpress/) may do the trick for you. There are also various iptables plugins for tracking individual IM services

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not so much looking to monitor network traffic as I'm looking for a way to use an IM client (adium,trillian,beejive,etc) on various devices and networks (home, work, 3g) and have my personal chat logs consolidated and searchable.

Answer (score 0):

www.paracalls.com centrally operates yahoo messenger, AOL, msn, GTalk by one click

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run a server, you could run an OpenFire server ( http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp ) which has plugins to connect to the various IM networks in addition to serving as a Jabber host (which can federate (interoperate) with Google Talk natively as well). It also includes logging and other enterprise-level IM features, and works with a variety of Jabber clients (including Spark, from the same company).

Answer (score 0):

Try to register jabber account on [Jabbim](http://www.jabbim.com) servers. It does support:

- connection to all mentioned networks through the transports,
- web-based interface to server-side history called Jabbim archive

Although use of Jabbim account is free, JabbIM archive is one of the benefits of sponsoring (VIP). VIP membership costs about 12 USD/year. More information about VIP is Czech version of the site, but you can use Google translator.